# Itertools partial lists python

Tags: python

I have the foll. list in python:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there an python itertools function that results in foll:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is trivial without itertools:

```
def fall(it):
    ls = []
    for x in it:
        ls.append(x)
        yield ls

for x in fall(xrange(20)):
    print x
```

Note that this works with any iterable, not just a list.

If you still want itertools, something like this should work (py3):

```
for x in itertools.accumulate(map(lambda x: [x], it)):
     print(x)
```

Again, it's lazy and works with any iterable.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything in `itertools`, that I can think of, but this should work:

```
def incremental(L):
    for i in range(1, len(L)+1):
        yield L[:i]
```

Output:

```
In [53]: print(*incremental([1, 2, 3, 4]), sep='\n')
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is *must* to use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), you may use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) as:

```
from itertools import islice
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(1, len(my_list)+1):
    print list(islice(my_list, i))
```

However there is absolutely no need to use `itertools` here. You may achieve this via simple *list slicing* as:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print my_list[:i+1]
```

Both of the above solutions will print the result as:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as one-liner using list comprehension:

```
>>> [ list[:x+1] for x in range(len(list)) ]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution, using [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) and [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html),

```
from itertools import islice
from functools import partial
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

[list(l) for l in map(partial(islice, my_list), range(1,len(my_list)+1))]
```

you get,

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

in other words,

```
from itertools import islice
from functools import partial
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p = partial(islice, my_list)
for i in range(1,5):
    print(list(p(i)))
```

you get,

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `itertools`, just use a map:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for sub_list in map(lambda index: l[:index + 1], range(len(l))):
...     print sub_list
```